# How to allow JS script to use certain variables

Tags: javascript, browser, scope, global, named-scope

I'm trying to make game, where you have to program AI for your bot. I know you can  access variable from your code with whole map `window.myGame.data.map` and you can modify it, for example, erase other bots.
How can I prevent this? Is there sandbox mode that script can use just methods of an Allowed object?
Is it a good idea to change window variable to custom Object?
Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide variables in JavaScript by means of closures. There is a good explanation how to do this here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html.

With ES6, you can also use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), that will also make use of closures to hide information, but it will be abstracted.